# How to Provide An Origin's First-Party Cookies When Calling it as a Third-Party

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, cross-domain, third-party-cookies

Suppose I own a website at "`cookiemaker.com`". I want my client (website owners themselves) to send HTTP requests to my server that include cookies I generated. In other words:

1. End-User "Bob" visits my site at cookiemaker.com
2. I (`cookiemaker.com`) provides him with a cookie that his browser now stores
3. Bob is now visiting another website ("`cool-recipes.com`")
4. Bob clicks a button within cool-recipes.com, then his browser sends an HTTP request to `cookiemaker.com`.

Is there a way to include the cookie created at (2) in the request sent at (4)?

(Assuming full control of both websites)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP cookies are always sent to the url requested, the origin requesting it (`cool-recipes.com`) should have a response with a header as the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin> //The website requester
```

If this header is not present, you will get an error like the following:

```
Access to fetch at '<requested site>' from origin '<your site>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

You have to add the origin (`cool-recipes.com`) to the site requested response headers (`cookiemaker.com`).

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://cool-recipes.com
```